# symfony: what should I install/do to "accelerate" my website?

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I have deploy a website in the production enviroment, but it's going a bit slow, you know it takes too much time to load the pages..

What should I install to "accelerate" my website? I read something about APL, or ADL (I can't remember the name..)

sf 1.4

Regards

Javi

Comment: You should install RAM, an SSD RAID configuration, and more cores.

Comment: You mean APC I guess: http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php

Comment: belongs on http://serverfault.com/ Q&A for system administrators and desktop support professionals

Comment: Good call on APC - Be wary though, while I've not used it myself, many of my colleagues have mentioned that it can make debugging a nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't gave us much info here...

- use a profiler/debugger like xdebug http://xdebug.org/ to see where the bottlenecks are
- use an upcode cache like http://eaccelerator.net/ or http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php
- update the server hardware(increase the RAM)
- use another webserver except apache( http://nginx.net/ , http://www.lighttpd.net/ )
- use a caching mechanism for on different layers (DB or page) http://www.sitepoint.com/caching-php-performance/ , http://www.igvita.com/2008/02/11/nginx-and-memcached-a-400-boost/
- use a CDN http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network
- partition your database http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28database%29 , http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning.html (assuming you use mysql)
- if the server load is high, then add another hdd, and put them in RAID. Also a and a multi-code CPU might help(depending on your specific website)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a great list of all the things you should do when deploying symfony, including adding an opcode cache: http://symfony-check.org/